# The error notes that Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration when debug the LZO

Tags: visual-studio-2015, lzo

I have compiled the original codes of lzo by cmake and I tried to debug the VS project lzo.sin,but the hint of VS noted that

```
#error:  Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration,
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oyvlj.png)

Then I find someone said it was because of the VS2015 had defined snprintf,the codes in the project also defined it,hence came the errors.I replaced the codes  `#define snprintf _snprintf` in the lzo_supp.h file with

```
#  ifndef
#    define snprintf _snprintf
#  endif
```

but the errors still remained.I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1900 
#define snprintf _snprintf
#endif
```

Still learning c++, started a few weeks ago, so I don't know EXACTLY how this fixes it, other then only having to define it on VS versions below 2015. Here's where  I found the answer
https://forum.juce.com/t/solved-error-with-vs2015-regarding-snprintf/14831/3

Comment: Doing this brings up linker issues.